# Elementor editor so slow

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

I have just started using elementor with wordpress.org 6.4.3 on a local machine (xampp) with Linux xfce4.
However, I am having a problem with loading times. The Elwementor editor is taking AGES to load.

I have tried the following:

-Changing theme
-Clearing the cache
-Changed the Switch Editor Loader Method to enable.
-Started Safe mode
However, none of these resolves the issue of the elementor editor taking ages to load!

Any help would be most appreciated!